# Error con Font-Awesome

Tags: javascript, css, html5, font-awesome

Cuando intento usar fontawesome, me aparece con un ícono raro como si no lo reconociera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hubiera alguna falla por farvor :'v

```
<body>
    <main>
        <em class="fa-solid fa-bars"></em>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es posible que te falte enlazar el estilo CSS de fontawesome en tu head

Comment: Comprueba la version que estas usando. Esa sintaxis parece de la version 6. Aqui se ve bien: https://jsfiddle.net/20dgwvj8/

Answer (score 0):

En principio verifica que que haces referencia a la librería **Fontawesome** correctamente.

mediante **CDN cloudfire**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--Referencia CSS-->
  <link href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
<!--Script JS-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<head>
```

Si descargaste la librería y la pusiste en tu servidor haces referencia a la ruta de alojamiento.
**Ejemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--Font Awsome local-->
    <link href="../../librarys/fontawesome-5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="../../librarys/fontawesome-5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Si tus referencias están correctas, verifica la sintaxis del **Icon**, ya que solo puedes utilizar iconos de forma **libre** o **gratis**, a menos que tengas una licencia de FontAwsome, al buscar iconos utiliza el filtro de gratis y prueba con esos.